# Unhandled Malformed URL Exception

Tags: android, compiler-errors

I created a separate method to prepare my query to Google places:

```
public URL getPlacesUrl (String stringLocation){

        try{
        String url = Uri.parse(PLACES_REQUEST_URL).buildUpon().
                appendQueryParameter("key", API_KEY).
                appendQueryParameter("radius", Integer.toString(SEARCH_RADIUS)).
                appendQueryParameter("location", stringLocation).
                appendQueryParameter("sensor", "true").build().toString();

        URL parsedURL = new URL(url);
        return parsedURL;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e){
            Log.e(TAG , "Malformed URLException caught : " + e);
        }

    }
```

I'm getting an error for "This method must return a result type of URL".
I understand that this is the result of the exception block that doesnt return a URL so I tried to return an empty URL:

```
URL emptyURL = new URL ("");
return emptyURL;
```

but then i'm getting a compiler error for "unhanded MalformedURLException"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were getting that because it wasn't within your `try/catch` block. But it's better not to try and parse an empty string. Try this:

```
public URL getPlacesUrl (String stringLocation){
    URL parsedURL = null;
    try {
        String url = Uri.parse(PLACES_REQUEST_URL).buildUpon().
            appendQueryParameter("key", API_KEY).
            appendQueryParameter("radius", Integer.toString(SEARCH_RADIUS)).
            appendQueryParameter("location", stringLocation).
            appendQueryParameter("sensor", "true").build().toString();

        parsedURL = new URL(url);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e){
        Log.e(TAG , "Malformed URLException caught : " + e);
    }
    return parsedURL;
}
```

The constructor for `URL` throws `MalformedURLException`. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL%28java.lang.String%29).